A combination question about the way to split a rectangle
A $m$ by $n$ rectangle which is consist of $mn$ unit squares is given.Link some of the $(m+1)(n+1)$ vertices to form $2mn$ triangles which any of these triangles have an area of $\frac{1}{2}$,the ways to link these points are written as $f(m,n)$.Find the expression of $f(m,n)$(If it doesn't have an expression,find its lower bound and upper bound)
I have thought on this question for a while,but I can only figure out that $f(1,n)=C^n_{2n}$ and $f(2,2)=64$.
sorry for my poor english.

Is it possible to derive a similar recurrence relation like Catalan numbers, like $f(m+1,n+1) = \sum_{i,k} f(i, k) f(m-i, n - k)$? At least this is a lower bound.

I have thought that way, but it seems to be way more complicated than I expected

Then how about $f(m, n) \ge \sum_{j=1}^{m-1} f(j, n) f(m-j, n)$, it is exactly Catalan sequence with your starting value as $C_{2n}^n$. My previous comment should be the product of 4 terms. btw.

My first try, which might easily completely fail to make any inroad into the problem, would be heron's formula.  At least this (initial) approach has the advantage of not having to deal with the angles formed by the vertices of any specific triangle.

@Yimin Yes that is really an interesting lower bound.But I think the precise answer is something like $f(m,n)=\sum_{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_k=n(k>=2)}(-1)^k f(a_1,n)f(a_2,n)\cdots f(a_k,n)$

Do these recurrence relations come from counting the configurations that can be obtained by placing two smaller configurations next to each other? I imagine most configurations don't look like that.

@Karl So I get this conclusion by spliting the rectangle into smaller ones,and similar to the principle of inclusion-exclusion,you also need to subtract the duplicated ones
